# how to get() relationships 3 level deep in data mapper in code igniter?

Tags: database, codeigniter, foreign-keys, datamapper, has-many

I am designing a database with the code igniter datamapper.
Imagine that I have a three tables one with users and one with friends and one with foods friend like. I am trying to access the food friend like. I have populated all the tables with data mapper.
Here is how I do it:

`user` table has `id`, `user_name`, `gender`, `user_id` fields.

Every user has many friends and friend table is:

`friend` table has `id`, `friend_id`, `friend_name`, `user_id`

Every friend has many foods and here is table for it:
`friend id` `food`

I was able to populate the tables by filing out the values. Lets say for example:

```
user:
1 andy male 394 
2 jen  female 439
..

friend:
1 243 mark 394
2 493 silvia 394
3 459 gloria 439
...
```

So when I try to access friend of a user from the database I do this:

```
$u->get_by_user_id($data['user']['id']);

if ($u->exists())
{ 
$data['user']['first_name'] = $u->first_name;
$data['user']['last_name'] = $u->last_name;
$data['user']['gender'] = $u->gender;
$data['user_friends']=$u->friend->get();
```

and it works...(i don't know why it knows what is the id of friend to relate to) but it works...
now I am trying to go one level deeper and access or get() every users' friends foods...but I do't know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer:

```
 if ($u->exists())
{ 
$data['user_profile']['first_name'] = $u->first_name;
    $data['user_profile']['last_name'] = $u->last_name;
$data['user_friends']=$u->friend->get();

foreach($u->friend->get()->all as $u){

$fm=new Food();
$fm->get_by_friend_id($u->friend_id)->get();

foreach($fm->all as $fm){
//stuff
          }
}
```

Comment: It'd be great if you could answer your own question with specifics on the configuration required to do this.  That way, you can accept your own answer and this thread remains a good resource for people with a related issue in the future..

Comment: If you take the `$fm = new Food();` out of the foreach-loop, the performance will increase! Just use `$fm->clear();` at the top inside the loop.

Connections between models are done through relationsships: [Check the datamapper docs](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/relationtypes.html).